# Opacity outside browser window becomes solid

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am getting a very weird behavior across all browsers when using rgba to make a div have a background with opacity.

Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/ma9AsEqINvnN

CSS for the opacity: `background: rgba(255,255,255,.8)`

What happens is the opacity becomes solid where the browser window ended. As you scroll, the opacity/solid line scrolls up the page. So what was visible without scrolling is opaque and what required scrolling is solid.

URL: http://www.ashwebdev.com/fleetridge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `height:100%;` from `#wrapper` in your CSS.

It is forcing your background image to only be the initial height of the viewable area of the document.